# How to create Component inside folder in Angular 6

Tags: angular, angular6

I've attached folder hierarchy of my angular project below:

[image]

As you can here. My app folder is under _component folder. also, my other ts files like auth is under _auth folder, interfaces are inside _model folder etc.

You when I execute `ng g c componentName` command, it creates app folder in root and create component inside it. so I have to go to particular folder and then I need to execute command.

[image]

My question is, is there anyway that I can create component direct from my root folder. like `ng g c _component/MycomponentName`

Updated:
I've also tried other ways to create it like below:
[image]
[image]

Comment: Exactly like you just said. `ng g component path/to/name`

Comment: This is the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46851416/7020538

Comment: Or you could make your life, and the life of all the developers maintaining this code, easier by respecting the standard layout.

Comment: @AbhijithS - I checked that post. he has taken _component folder inside app folder. My situation is opposite of it. my app folder is inside _Component folder

Answer (score 2):

This is the normal command, to be run in the project root.

```
ng g c path/to/name
```

But due to your non-standard project structure, `ng` is failing to find the NgModule in which your new component should be imported. So you either can use the `--skip-import` option, or the `--module path/to/your/app/module` option and point `ng` to the right file

Comment: I tried that as well. but still same error. You can check screenshot I've attached

Comment: @UbiquitousDevelopers see my updated answer, let me know if it's not clear enough

Answer (score 1):

[image: how to create Component inside folder in Angular example with image]

ANS : ng generate component auth/reset-password

Answer (score 0):

It's better to change your project structure into standard angular project structure like this.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i6fKS.png)

then you can generate new component moving relevant place through terminal and type

> ng g c  *component name*

Answer (score 0):

Better you could use following folder structure and get rid of that error so that you can
create modules and components accordingly.

```
-app
  
-shared
  -services
  -pipes
  -components
  -models

-modules_folder
  -module_A
    -components_folder
        -component_A.component.ts
        -component_A.component.html
        -component_A.component.css            
    -models_folder
        -model_A.model.ts
    -services_folder
        -service_A.service.ts

    -module_A.component.ts 
    -module_A.component.html
    -module_A.component.css
    -module_A.module.ts        
    -module_A-routing.module.ts  

-app.component.ts
-app.component.html
-app.component.css
-app.module.ts
-app-routing.module.ts
```

Above folder structure gives a kind of micro-service architecture as well where each module having its own services/dependencies.